# Local property of dimension

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. If the Krull dimensions of all the localizations $S^{-1}R$ are zero, where $S$ runs among multiplicative subsets of $R$, is it true that the Krull dimension of $R$ is zero?

If the dimension of a given localization is zero is that of $R$ zero?

For $S$ a multiplicative subset of $R$, it is known that $\dim S^{-1}R \le \dim R$, therefore if the right hand side is zero so is the other side.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chain of prime ideals $p_0\subset p_1\subset\dots \subset p_d$ induces a chain of the same length in $S^{-1}R$ if and only if $S\subset R-p_d$. Therefore, if $R$ is of finite dimension, then $\mathrm{dim}(S^{-1}R)=\mathrm{dim}(R)$ if and only if there is a maximal ideal $m\subset R$ of maximal height such that $S\subset R- m$. In particular, we can just take $S=R-m$.

Thus, there is a non-trivial localisation $S^{-1}R\not= R$ of the same (finite) dimension if and only if $R$ is not local. Namely, if $m$ is any prime ideal of maximal height, then $S:=R-m$ will do the job, whilst it can't consist of units only since otherwise $m$ would be local.

To address the two questions directly:

1. If $S^{-1}R$ has dimension zero for all multiplicative $S\subset R$, then $R$ has dimension zero too, for the trivial reason that we can take $S=\{1\}$. If we want a non-trivial localisation with this property, we have to assume that $R$ is not local.
2. *Does $\mathrm{dim}(S^{-1}R)=0$ for some $S$ imply that $\mathrm{dim}(R)=0$*? No! Take $S:=R-p$ for any minimal prime. Then $\mathrm{dim}(S^{-1}R)=0$, no matter what the dimension of $R$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true since $\{1\}$ is a multiplicative subset and the localization of $R$ by $\{1\}$ is $R$.

Comment: What you say is true, but it seems unlikely the same thought would not have occurred to the OP.

Comment: Is this  answering the question ?

Comment: It certainly answers the first part.  Note the brief second paragraph, which (vaguely) seems to ask about "a given localization" (rather than "all the localizations").  Your Answer points out that the first part is trivial.